# Can't import deployJava.js

Tags: javascript, java

I am making an applet to sign PDF on client side and everything is working fine locally. I tried today to use it on my Virtual Machine to simulate the server and now I can't get deployJava to  work. I get the following error :

```
-> deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
"deployJava" is not defined.
```

I am using Internet Explorer EDGE, Virtual Box with bridged option enabled. And here is my **HTML code** :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

<form method='post' id='formUpload' name='formUpload' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/piece-jointe/add' target='hiddeniframe' >
                <dt>Hello
                <script>
                        var attributes = {
                                  codebase: './applet/',
                                  code: 'PDFSigningApplet',
                                  archive: 'jars/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar, ' +
                                          'jars/bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar, ' +
                                          'jars/signing-pdf-applet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, ' +
                                          'jars/commons-imaging-1.0-20170517.221134-118.jar, ' +
                                          'jars/commons-io-2.4.jar, ' +
                                          'jars/itextpdf-5.5.11.jar, ' +
                                          'jars/itext-pdfa-5.5.11.jar, ' +
                                          'jars/itext-xtra-5.5.11.jar, ' +
                                          'jars/xmlworker-5.5.11.jar',
                                  width: '150',
                                  height: '30',
                                  mayscript: 'true'
                                 };
                        var parameters = {java_arguments: ''}; // customize per your needs Xmx256m
                        var version = '1.8'; // JDK version
                        //getJREs();
                        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
                        console.log("Ran script");
                </script>
```

I have Java JRE 1.6 on my VM and 1.8 on my PC locally.
Am I doing something wrong ?

**EDIT :** il also keeps redirecting me to java.com everytime I double click the button to launch my applet.

Comment: applets is an old technology that's going to be deprecated in Java 9, Just so you know